# Please stay active, atleast till the site is in beta stage

Tags: discussion, beta

I have my eyes on the sites statistics everyday on Area51 and it seems like we are rapidly going down with the visitors rate per day.

I agree that the site is in Private Beta so we can't expect 1000's of visitors straight away but what am seeing is that people used to be much more active for the first three days and later, they just visit and leave.

Inorder to get this site promoted we need to work as a team and help out each other over this. Most of the people over here are Indians, I have never seen more than 4-5 users in a room at the same time and yes, even between 10AM to 10PM *(GMT +5.30)* which is not good atleast for private stage where the quality of the site contents matter the most so we need to have few active users who generally clean up the mess over here.

As I counted active users roughly, they sum up to 20/210 users *[(210 as per Area51)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism)* which is somewhat around 10% where at this stage I expect the count to be around 30% to 40% atleast.

Things you should do while you are active *(Even for few minutes)*

- Edit questions, retag them, fix grammar, leave helpful comments
- Close vote off topic questions
- Keep a check on the review queue
- Upvote/Downvote posts and leave appropriate comments
- Participate in meta discussions
- Participate in Chat Rooms
- Flag inappropriate posts

The reason of posting this questions is that I am visiting the chat room since Friday and there is no active discussion whatsoever, be it an on topic or off, I am aware that its a weekend still, I expect users, mostly the best ones which are here from the start to keep a check on stats and maintain the quality of the content on this website.

I would like to hear comments from other users over this, would appreciate your inputs.