# Can we be mature about close voting?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

This is an issue I have observed lately on main site. ***Pinpointing the close voters in comments***.

When a question is closed by the community, some users are losing their patience and and pointing and targetting close voters in the comments saying why is this off-topic, why is this primarily opinion based etc.,

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

<sup>darkened the commentator's name to prevent targetting</sup>

Above are only few examples of pin pointing users. It is not a single user who is doing it but there are some others too. So, this is not a meta post to bash them. There have been a handful instances where I have found such comments targetting the close voters and saying they are doing it purpose fully which they are not. Me and moderators know such instances and the users doing it. But here is the saddest part: Other users are upvoting those comments and supporting that pin pointing instead of trying to modify the question and finding ways to make questions eligible for reopening.

No one like their question to be closed but remember that it is not a single user or two who are not voting to close your question but the community is. One user's close vote doesn't make a question closed. It needs four more votes. If it is not those five members, it will be other five members. So,  If your questions are often revolving in both close vote and reopen queues, concentrate on the way you are asking the question instead of pin pointing the users who voted to close. If a user is always targetting your posts like a pattern even when the question is proper and perfect, it will be known to the moderators and the user who does that will be receiving will receive a message from moderators.  If this still continued, they will be review banned. Focus on *why* the question is closed and not *who* voted to close. This results in the damage of the spirit of community and it results in the site's performance also.

So, focus on *why* , not on *who*.

This discussion is not to target any user but to let them know that what is happening is wrong.

What can other users do when they find such comments,

- They can flag such comments with a "in the need of moderator intervention" and explain why the comment should be deleted.
- Try to explain the user why the question is closed and how they can reopen again.
- Go to [review](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/review) page and chose correct option which the post deserves ('Leave Closed' or 'Leave Open' etc., )

I also seek some more solutions from you in the form of answers to get rid of this bad practice of pinpointing users.

Comment: Nice effort. Better to split this post into Qn & answer. You are trying to convey a sincere message. But currently it appears as of an advice is disguised as Qn. I won't disagree with someone already close voting as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @iammilind and also the close voter, I am actually not asking anything except some more ways how to stop this practice. This is an advice. A [ meta-tag:discussion] need not to be a question. It can be a suggestion or an advice which is helpful for the community. I am starting a new discussion here. If you're not sure about this, check [meta-tag:faq]. Many of these questions have answers and discussions in them. Meta Stack Exchange also has posts like these. I am starting a discussion and also expect users to come up. This isn't unclear or POB question.

Comment: *"I am actually not asking anything except some more ways how to stop this practice. This is an advice."* -- That's why it's unclear. Your advice part is too long that it can be an answer. Sorry I couldn't get anything related out of "faq" tag link you posted. Though I upvoted the Qn for its intent, I realise that this Qn lacks objectivity. If it's closed, then I will re-ask in different form.

Comment: It will not closed as unclear what you are asking. Meta closure is different from main. If it does, I don't know to laugh or cry. See examples [Use OCR to post answers from PDFs which are not text searchable] (https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/616/5212), [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/5212) [Private beta extended - please focus on quality](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/92/5212)  [Please stay active, atleast till the site is in beta stage](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/120/5212). There are many more.

Comment: I have had questions closed and answers downvoted all over Stack Exchange as well as entire proposals in Area 51. It is very frustrating to put so much work into something and not be told *why* it is poor quality or *how* to improve it. Just because a question is poor doesn't mean the questioner isn't sincere in wanting to understand. So, in my case it has nearly driven me away from the SE community more than once. Not because of downvoting and closing, but because I am here to learn and help others learn. Without explanation or discussion these behaviors are anathema to learning and progress.